# Why using a pretrained model with dense variational for uncertainty estimates gives low accuracy?

Tags: uncertainty-quantification, tensorflow-probability

I try to a train model for real image classification and to estimate uncertainty by using [the TensorFlow Probability library](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability). For that, I am using a pretrained model as a feature extractor (the features used from the pretrained model) and then add the `DenseVariational` layer (I replace the dense layer with it). as a transfer-learning but instead of dense layer i put DenseVariational layer, since training Bayesian model (for conv layer also) is more complex and time consuming than standard deep learning model, so i use DenseNet169 as feature-extractor and then add DenseVariational for FC layer.

the idea for this to estimate uncertainty (to know the Values and reduce the uncertainty if its high) as the model when classify the image is class1 its certain and have high probability for that class1 when classified it as class1(which mean low uncertainty), and probability model one of these method for uncertainty.

The problem is when training the model, it gives me low accuracy (around 30 when using more dense-variational layer, and around 40% when using one dense-Variational layer), but it increases when retrain the model (train model multiple times) bit still the accuracy low. I tried the prior and posterior I found in the examples provides in documentation(tensorflow-probablity).

I also tried different priors and posteriors, but I got the same result, and I don't know why. Maybe it doesn't layer from previous layers, or learns the feature map.

Any notes? Or maybe combining the pre-trained model with probability layers is wrong? I provide the code below

this the code below for prior nd postrior

```
def prior(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    # Independent Normal Distribution
    return lambda t: tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=tf.zeros(n, dtype=dtype),
                                                scale=1),
                                     reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)

def posterior(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return Sequential([
        tfpl.VariableLayer(tfpl.IndependentNormal.params_size(n), dtype=dtype),
        tfpl.IndependentNormal(n)
    ])

kl_weight= (lambda q, p, _: tfd.kl_divergence(q, p) /  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
                            tf.cast(NUM_TRAIN_EXAMPLES, dtype=tf.float32))
```

the model:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet169(
    input_shape=(224,224,3),
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    classes=3)
for layer in base_model.layers[:-10]:
    layer.trainable = False
x = base_model.output
x =  GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tfpl.DenseVariational(units=128,
                          make_prior_fn = prior,
                          make_posterior_fn = posterior,
                          kl_weight= 1/NUM_TRAIN_EXAMPLES)(x)
x = tfpl.DenseVariational(units=32,
                          make_prior_fn = prior,
                          make_posterior_fn = posterior,
                          kl_weight= 1/NUM_TRAIN_EXAMPLES)(x)'''
x = tfpl.DenseVariational(units=3,
                          make_prior_fn = prior,
                          make_posterior_fn = posterior,
                          kl_weight= 1/NUM_TRAIN_EXAMPLES)(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
```

and the loss function is nll(negative-likelihood)

```
def nll(y_true, y_pred):
    return -y_pred.log_prob(y_true)
```

Comment: On what basis do you think that you can just replace a dense layer with a variational layer and get the results you need, which are unspecified? Have you seen somewhere that you can do this?

Comment: well, like transfer learning I think that way, why to train model from scratch with bayesain layer (for conv layer) which is complexs and time consuming  if i can use the feature map?? and  want to have good accurcy and able to estimate uncertainty(to konw the valuses and reduce the uncertainty if its high) as the model when classify the image is class1 its certain and have high probablity for that class1 when classifed it as class1.

Comment: And i didn't see it in research, reasearch talk about using monte carlo dropout, wich is add dropout layer in the structure of the model betwwen the conv layer also not berfor FC layer. and actully there's confused and not understandable ideas, and all talk about the same subject, but didn't find the clear to implement this ideas

Comment: I've tried to improve the clarity of your post. Can you please check the post's body and title are consistent with your original intention/question? Can you also please add this info you've just added in the comments to your post too? Could also specify exactly which prior and posterior you're using or you tried? You said you tried the ones in the documentation, but you don't specify the link to the documentation or the actual names. Can you also specify what accuracy or "uncertainty estimates" you're having?

Comment: Also, what is the pre-trained model? Which loss function are you using? How are you training or fine-tuning? It would be better if you provide the link to the full code. Thanks for providing answers to all these questions.

Comment: thank for concern and clarification, i added above the prior and postrior and  i edit my question, for accuracy is 30-40, loss function i added above and can using caterogical-crossentropy but when training the loss became large.

Comment: for prior and posterior i found it in tensorflow-probability website and it also explained in course on coursera called  Probabilistic Deep Learning with TensorFlow 2 : Imperial College London